# Why does this for-loop and while-loop produce different outcomes, even though their values are the same? Btw I am using Javascript

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

My novice understanding of the difference between for-loops and while-loops is that they differ in format and we use for-loops when we know the exact number of iterations to complete and we use while-loops when we know what condition must be met to stop. That said could someone explain the difference in outcome of the following code?

```
let countDown = 2;

while(countDown>1){
    countDown--;
    console.log(countDown)    
}

1

for(let countDown = 2; countDown>1; countDown--){
    console.log(countDown)
}

2
```

Comment: Maybe re-check the semantics of `for`: Your `while` loop simply isn't equivalent. Also `for` is just "syntactic sugar" for a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As  [U. Windl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6607497/u-windl)  had commented, `for` is just "syntactic sugar" for a `while` loop. The output of your program varied for `for` and `while` loop because in while loop `countDown` is decremented first and then logged, in `for` loop `countDown` is logged first and then decremented. With the below change in while loop the output would be same for both and its equivalent to `for` loop.

```
let countDown = 2;

while(countDown>1){
    console.log(countDown)   
    countDown--; 
}
```

Lets see what `for` and `while` loop says [JavaScript For Loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

```
The For Loop

The for loop has the following syntax:
for (statement 1; statement 2 (condition); statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}

Statement 1 is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.
Statement 2 defines the condition for executing the code block.
Statement 3 is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

While Loop

while (condition) {
      // code block to be executed
}
```

In your program in `for` loop `Statement 3` (i.e countDown--) is executed after the code block (i.e console.log) has been executed, that is the reason the output was 2.

In `while` loop we have to take care when to execute `Statement 3` (i.e countDown-- in this case) and in `for` loop `Statement 3` is always executed after executing `code block`

`for` equivalent for `while`

```
for (; condition; ) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

`while` equivalent for `for`

```
Statement 1
while (Statement 2) {
  // code block to be executed
  Statement 3
}
```